# How to cite a Linkedin Profile in IEEE format?

Tags: citation-style, website, ieee

The [IEEE standard](http://www.ijssst.info/info/IEEE-Citation-StyleGuide.pdf) specifies said format for all website citations:

> **World Wide Web**
>
> Author(s)*. “Title.” Internet: complete URL, date
>   updated* [date accessed]. M. Duncan. “Engineering Concepts on Ice.
>   Internet: www.iceengg.edu/staff.html, Oct. 25, 2000 [Nov. 29, 2003].

In particular to Linkedin profiles, the format I decided on so far looks like this:

> John Doe. "John Doe." Internet: https://www.linkedin.com/in/johndoe/, 2017. [Nov. 10, 2017]

Is this the correct format for a linkedin profile?

Comment: You can't cite a linkedin profile, could be gone the next day and there is no publicly accessible archive. If you absolutely think you have to mention it, do that in-text.

Comment: You can cite a LinktedIn profile, it is just the same as citing the world wide web. I'd recommend including the citation as a footnote rather than in the bibliography. (This is recommended elsewhere -- perhaps in some style guides -- but I forget where. Perhaps you can search for it.) There are some services that will cache web pages for research purposes. (I forget which ones. Again, perhaps you can search for one.) Citing such a URL might be preferable (albeit, I'm not yet convinced) to citing the actual URL.

Comment: Why do you want to cite it? Do you want to do this often (in which case working out a long term archiving solution might be more desireable)? I'd try to find the information in a more durable format if at all possible...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Print a copy of the document as a pdf, and host the document on your public Dropbox directory. Then cite it as a webpage, corresponding to the location of Dropbox directory.